# Script to remove print jobs with more of one hour of "time life"

Tags: powershell

I'm making a script to manage all the print jobs of the server, so far i managed to erase only the jobs with the status "Complete", I added a if, which in case of the printjob is older than 1 hour, the script should remove the job.

I'm not really sure about this to be working, it seems to erase it all, so i'm not sure where i'm failing, plus the scripts goes to the else condition always.

```
$nombre = hostname

$old = (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)

Write-Host $nombre
if (Get-Printer -ComputerName $nombre  | Get-Printjob | where {$_.timesubmitted -lt $old -and $_.JobStatus -match "Complete" -and $_.JobStatus -notmatch "Spooling"} | Remove-PrintJob){ 
      Write-Host "Eliminados los trabajos completados mas antiguos de una hora" } 
else { 
      Write-Host "No se han encontrado trabajos que coincidan con los parametros"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you will need to format your `if` condition. Try this -

```
if (Get-Printer -ComputerName $nombre)
{
    get-printjob | where {$_.timesubmitted -lt $old -and $_.JobStatus -match "Complete" -and $_.JobStatus -notmatch "Spooling"} | Remove-PrintJob
    Write-Host "Eliminados los trabajos completados mas antiguos de una hora"
}
else
    Write-Host "No se han encontrado trabajos que coincidan con los parametros"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should look more like this:

```
$nombre = hostname

$old = (Get-Date).AddHours(-1)

Write-Host $nombre

$Printjobs = Get-Printer -ComputerName $nombre  | Get-Printjob | where {$_.timesubmitted -lt $old -and $_.JobStatus -match "Complete" -and $_.JobStatus -notmatch "Spooling"}

if($Printjobs){
  foreach($job in $PrintJob)
  {
    Remove-PrintJob $job
    Write-Host "Eliminados los trabajos completados mas antiguos de una hora"
  } 
  else{ 
      Write-Host "No se han encontrado trabajos que coincidan con los parametros"
  }
}
```

This way you first check if there is any old print job, and then stop every old one.